# Remove all the svn files in all the macosx directories

Tags: macos, file, svn

I would like to run a command to remove all the .svn files in my macosx.

Is it possible or is better to remove them just from directory by directory?

How can i do that?

thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `find` to recursively locate and delete Subversion metadata folders:

```
find . -name .svn -exec rm -rf '{}' +
```

Comment: need to specify directory? how if i need?

Comment: I assume you'd replace the first `.` with `/path/to/mydir`.

Comment: I just noticed that you said you were running OSX.  The above should work in any Linux-style shell that has the standard utilities `find` and `rm`.  I believe that covers OSX, but I don't have an OSX machine to verify.

Comment: @corsiKa- That is correct.  The `.` indicates the starting directory of the search.  If you don't want to run this on the current directory, replace `.` with whatever path you need.

Answer (score 2):

svn export will do a copy of all the files without the .svn and then you can remove the old folder if that's what you are going for.

Comment: This might be a better solution.

Comment: Note that this might take a while if you have a very large working copy since it involves a copy.

Comment: Good point. Depending on the size of the files and amount of files, this could take quite some time.

Comment: I guess for future reference when you are taking from the repository do an svn export instead if you don't plan on committing your work. Then you wont have to remove anything.